# how can i add dynamic image from database into html table form i have the error

Tags: php, html, css, html-table

i stuck into the table data i get all the data but the images is not retrive i have the uploads folder which have all the store images below is my code.

```
<td>'.$row['picture'].'</td>
```

this picture only get the url but how i can get with the actuall image

```
   <?php
     $query=$conn->query("select * from missing");
     $sn=0;
     while($row=$query->fetch_array())
     {
     $sn++;
      echo '<tr>
      <td>'.$sn.'</td>
      <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row['father_name'].'</td>

      <td>'.$row['age'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row['color'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row['height'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row['gender'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row['district_id'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row['description'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row['address'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row['missing_date'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row['picture'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row['status'].'</td>

      <td><a href="function.php?type=deleteuser&userid='.$row['id'].'"<i class="fa fa-trash" aria- 
      hidden="true"></i></a></td>

      <td><a href="function.php?type=deleteuser&userid='.$row['id'].'"<i class="fa fa-edit" aria- 
       hidden="true"></i></a></td>

       </tr>
      ';
      }
       ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the HTML `img` tag to display an image.

`<img src="'.$row['picture'].'"/></td>` for starters.
I see some other problems but you're clearly a beginner and I won't berate you about them...

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'src' (T_STRING), expecting ';' or ',' in C:\xampp\htdocs\missing_person\user\all_missing_person.php on line 77

Comment: post the entire line of code you have that includes img. you have a quote in the wrong place, this error means PHP is trying to treat the HTML as PHP code.

Comment: . actually the main reason is the <tr> is inside the php tag and when i put <img> its shows that error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display multiple images you can use many to many relationship...
You must have one table with image information second table with image name and third table that stores only the id's. then select image and loop throw ids

Answer (score 0):

```
use **<img>** tag 

ie,
<td><img src=path_to_image_folder/'.$row['picture'].'></td>
```

Comment: everything has an reason, so it's better if you add some description to your answer, and explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Now i add successfully image from database through this code

```
<td><img src='.$row['picture'].'></td>
```

but when i inspect the that image the file path is incorrect
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM4WF.png)